# Flutter - How to change the color of the text being selected by the cursor?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, themedata

I need to change the color of the text being highlighted by the cursor. I am able to chagne the color of cursor, its selction and handler using `textSelectionTheme`. But, how can I change the color of the highlighted text?

`ThemeData` so far.

```dart
get _lightTheme => ThemeData(
      disabledColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
      textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: AppPalette.primaryColorLight,
        selectionColor: AppPalette.primaryColorLight.withOpacity(0.5),
        selectionHandleColor: AppPalette.primaryColorLight,
      ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as of now. You can track this link in github

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99231